# Pin UVs for Pack Islands?

Tags: uv, workflow

Pin allows me to keep parts of a mesh where it is while performing a subsequent unwrap operation. Is it possible to pin objects so they do not move when performing *Pack Islands*?

Comment: I think you needn't pin parts to do that. Pack Islands only affects on selections.

Comment: @LeonCheung But it will pack over the unselected parts.

Comment: Yes, it will. I don't think we got one-stop solution for it yet. But let's see if others can provide something fresh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, currently pack is based on the selection only. It could be handy to have a way to select only unpinned UV islands so you could use them as a way to lock islands for other tools.